# gridview is displaying incorrect data from database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

when i am trying to display data in gridview using choose data-source option it is displaying incorrect data. There is no code in .cs file only aspx file has code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="emp_id" AlternatingRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="emp_id" HeaderText="emp_id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="emp_id" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="asset_type" HeaderText="asset_type" SortExpression="asset_type" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="asset_name" HeaderText="asset_name" SortExpression="asset_name" />
   </Columns>
   <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
   <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
   <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
   <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
   <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
   <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
   <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
   <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
   <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=AssetDB" DefaultContainerName="AssetDB" EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="asset_request">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

[image]

Back-end code

```
public partial class Request : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: as i said there is no backend code public partial class Request : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing a simple SQL select query on your page load event and see whether now data loads correctly or not.

```
public partial class Request : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try{
          string query = "select * from asset_request";
          SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString");
          con.Open();
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
          
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
          da.SelectCommand = cmd;  
          da.Fill(dt);
          if(dt != null)
          {
             GridView1.DataSource= dt;
             GridView1.DataBind();
          }
          con.Close();
        } 
        catch(Exception ex) { 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it with sql it is working but i still want to know why it is not working with entity framework

Comment: @brutospop delete your Gridview and re-bind everything. Then Go to Your Solution Explorer > Clean your Solution (by right clicking on your project) >  Re-build and then Run.

Comment: @brutospop it might be possible that you are pointing to some other database with same table name. EF maps incorrect data in such cases. Try removing everything and rebinding as I mentioned.